# Show that $x^2+4x+17$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^3)$ but that $x^3$ is not $\mathcal{O}(x^2+4x+17)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This proof for Big-O analysis of the the function mentioned in question is done in two parts:

**Part I** $x^2+4x+17$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^3)$: In this part we can set $k=10$ and we can still get that $x^2+4x+17$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^3)$, but I found based on an answer that the value is $k=17$. We can see that:

$$x^2+4x+17\le x^2 + x^2 + x^2$$
$$ = 3x^2$$

**Question 1**: We can conclude that $C=3$ and $k=17$. But I am not sure why $k=17$ and not $k=10$ for example?

**Part II** $x^3$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^2+4x+17)$: In this part we can set $k=17$, and then proceed the proof by contradiction to arrive that:

$$\mid x^3\mid \le C\mid 3x^2\mid$$
$$$$

**Question 2**: in the proof it's mentioned that we have a contradiction because $\mid x^3\mid \gt \mid 3C x^2\mid$ when $x>3C$. I think taht $\mid x^3\mid$ is always greater than $\mid 3C x^2\mid$ not only $x>3C$, so I don't understand his conclusion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of Big-O states that $f(x) \in \mathcal{O}(g(x))$ if and only if there exist constants $C, k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C \cdot |g(x)|$ for all $x \geq k$.

The solutions may have picked $k = 17$ for convenience, but $k = 10$ seems to also check out. Note that the quantifier in the definition is existential. It does not exclude other valid pairs for $(C, k)$.

**Edit:** For the second part, you need to rule out all $(C, k)$ pairs, not just pairs where $k = 17$. Try instead the following.

Suppose that $(C, k)$ satisfies that $|x^{3}| \leq C|x^{2} + 4x + 17|$ for all $x \geq k$. We exhibit a value of $x \geq k$ for which this inequality fails to hold. From the previous part, we showed that $x^{2} + 4x + 17 \leq 3x^{2}$ for $x \geq 17$. So to achieve our contradiction, it suffices to show that $|x^{3}| \geq 3C \cdot |x^{2}|$ for some $x \geq k$. Solving for $x$, we obtain that $|x^{3}| \leq C|x^{2} + 4x + 17|$ fails to hold whenever $x > \max\{3C, k, 17\}$.

Comment: Why we take the absolute value in $\mathcal{O}$ definition $\mid f(x)\mid \le C⋅\mid g(x)\mid $

Comment: I have added the other part, which is a proof by contradiction. I added on more question based on the answer provided above for the second part.

Comment: I have updated my answer. In the future, it is better practice to post your entire question upfront or to use multiple threads. Updating your original post to add more parts is not really great practice. :-)

Comment: Thank you again, but I am still a little bit not sure as to why you replaced $C$ by $k$ as usually, $x>k$ and not $x>C$ when we try to find pair $(C,k)$.

Comment: Solving $|x^{3}| \geq 3C \cdot |x^{2}|$ yields that $x \geq 3C$ (provided $x \geq 0$). On the other hand, $|x^{3}| \leq C|x^{2} + 4x + 17|$ when $x \geq 17$ (from Part I), so we need to ensure that all of the following conditions hold: $x \geq k$, $x \geq 3C$, and $x \geq 17$.